# What is implied by "In the U.S" on the DS-160 application form?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

The application asks whether your parents, other immediate relatives, or other more distant relatives are in the U.S. Does "in" the U.S mean:

1. Resident in the U.S (temporary home)
2. Domiciled (permanent home)
3. Physically present (temporary or permanent) OR
4. Immigration status (citizen, LPR...)

For example: a dual USA citizen who is living permanently in his other country of citizenship. Another scenario could be a U.S citizen who is temporarily working in another country with plans to return. Are either of them considered "in the U.S?" What if the person is away for a short visit and not physically in the U.S at the time of the application. Are they "in the U.S?"

Comment: Exactly what does the text state?

Comment: @Michael Hampton "Is your father in the US?" Replace father with mother...

Comment: "No, my father is not 'in' the US, for the next two hours he is over the Pacific Ocean on a flight from Honolulu to Los Angeles. My brother is a US astronaut on the International Space Station, and my mother is gambling at the casino in Windsor with her sister this weekend."

Answer (score 1):

The question implies domicile, not physical presence, as indicated by an individual status in the United States: US citizen, US legal permanent resident, employment, student, visitor. Presence and residence are separate for purposes of the information that should be provided in the DS-160 application.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is not clear. It's not necessary for a US citizen to be domiciled in the USA. Also, you haven't provided any citation about the source of your answer. Also, wouldn't a student "resident but not domiciled" in the USA be "in the USA?" The consular would want to know that. Anyways, I answered no for a relative domiciled but not resident in the USA. There was an indirect question about it in the interview because I was going to stay at her USA residence. The consular officer wasn't concerned about yes/no on the DS160.